# iAd not showing in Downloaded version of my app

Tags: ios, iad

I have made an app with iAd. It appeared both in simulator and my device when I deploy it. However, after the app is approved and up on store I downloaded it and cannot see the iAd. Anyone had this issue before?

Some of the iAd related code:

```
#pragma mark iAd delegate methods
-(void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [banner setAlpha:0.5];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

-(void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [banner setAlpha:0.0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

In viewDidLoad():

```
adView = [[[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, adY, 0, 0)] autorelease];
adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
adView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:adView];
adView.delegate=self;
```

adY is just a value based on the size of the screen.

Comment: Sometimes it can take a few days for Apple to start filling your ad space, so if your app has only been live for a few hours you may just need to wait. The iAd team also reviews your app upon it being released.
On the other hand setting [banner setAlpha:0.5]; should be banner.alpha = 1.0;. Your adView shouldn't have any transparency. Also, adView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor]; should be removed. There's no need to set a background color to your adView. What is the value of adY in this code CGRectMake(0, adY, 0, 0)]? Edit more code in your post if possible and I will post a full answer

Comment: It got approved for only a couple of days. I will see how it goes...Added explanation to adY anyway. Thanks for your ans.

Comment: I'd suggest just waiting then. If this is the initial release of your app it may be a problem on Apple's side. I've had issues with getting any ads filled on new releases until an update was submitted and approved. Also, make sure your iAd contract is up to date in iTunes Connect. I'd contact Apple directly and see if they have any input on the matter. Best of luck to you.

Answer (score 2):

It takes four days after for release for Apple to start filling advertisements in iAd.

Also, iAd only works in certain countries. It doesn't work all around the world. The only countries that iAd will show advertisements in are:

Australia, Canada, France, Germany, Hong Kong, Ireland, Italy, Japan, Mexico, New Zealand, Spain, Taiwan, United Kingdom and United States.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/iad/resources/

Some very large markets are missing from this list. If you are not in one of these countries you will not see advertisements.

Comment: Where are you getting the specific amount of days(4) from? I can tell you from personal experience that it can take as long as an hour to a week for ads to be filled.

Comment: Hi, I've used iAd's twice, and it took about 4 days both times. It could be that it was coincidence that it took the same amount of time both times. However I may not use iAd again so I may never know.