# Swift - Ad is just a white bar on the app

Tags: ios, swift, iad

I recently uploaded my app to the App Store, but when I downloaded it to check it out I realized that my app doesn't show anything just a white bar, I asked for a friend to try it out and the behavior is the same. When I debug it on my iphone or in the virtual device it appears that iAd ad (That one that explains how to create your own add). I wonder what might be happening, did I forgot to do any configuration?

**Edit:**  Ad still white!

Comment: possible duplicate of [iAd not showing in Downloaded version of my app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23710487/iad-not-showing-in-downloaded-version-of-my-app)

Comment: Oh, I searched for a question like that and I didn't found any. But, Thanks! I will make the feedback four days from now.

Comment: but why do you leave a white bar, when there's no iAd to display? You should test your App with a ad fillrate  < 100%

Comment: I didn't! It was suppose to hide. Sorry, ad fillrate?

Comment: Your device and the iOS Simulator should have a setting to control the fill rate of the iAds: `Settings > Developer > Fill Rate`.
You can use this setting to check the behaviour of the banner, if there are no ads to display.

Comment: I did the Fill Rate, set it to 0% and the withe bar is right there

Comment: Now you can find the bug, wich is responsible for the non hidden banner, wich seems to leave the white bar.

Comment: hmm, how should I do check if the app have received data on a if/else?

Comment: Just hide the banner by default and show it only after you receive the successful callback. This should be common pratice and shown in serveral tutorials.

Comment: Guys, I have waited for the four days, a bit more actually and when I went to check my app, nothing... The ads still not loading

Answer (score 1):

The white space you're seeing is an empty iAd banner because it did not receive an ad. You need to include the following delegate methods to hide the `ADBannerView` when it does not receive an ad, and display it when it does receive an ad.

```
func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    // Yes we have an ad. Lets show it
    adBannerView.alpha = 1.0
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    // No ad. Lets hide it
    adBannerView.alpha = 0.0
}
```